# I'm trying to match one of two values to an element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

It's a countdown 0-6 sometimes it idles//gets stuck at 0 I want it to wait till it's either "6" or "0" to do something.
I have tried these just works on the 6 i imagine because its the first value

```
def DoSomething():
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]"), "6"),
        EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]"), "0"))

    print("Do Something")
```

Comment: Which site are you testing? Can you give a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `or` condition of xpath:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2][contains(text(),'0') or contains(text(),'6')]")))
```

I cannot test it because you did not provide a link to the site you are looking at.